# Trouble booting OS

Tags: boot, operating-systems

I've two hard disks, one contains XP, the other contains Windows 7. By default, 7 used to boot up, but, now XP is booting up. Even boot options doesn't show Windows 7. How to get back Windows 7 now?

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Dual-boot Repair tool](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) in Windows XP.

Run it and click on "Automatic Repair".

Reboot - Windows 7 should be the default boot choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have a corrupted bootloader.

If you have Windows installation disk, then you can use that to boot into Windows Recovery Environment to rebuild bootloader

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootsect /nt60 all
bootrec /rebuild
```

[Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/8057-dual-boot-installation-windows-7-xp.html) is detailed+alternate instructions if you may need them